# Why does Django rest framework factory.get work with any path, even when it doesn't exist?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**tests.py**

```
class TestTodoAppUsers(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()

    def test_get(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/api/users')
        view = views.ListCreateTodoAppUsers.as_view()
        response = view(request)
        response.render()
        self.assertEqual(1, len(json.loads(response.content)))
```

I have not yet made the `urls.py`, so I would think that my get request wouldn't work, but it does.

Why does this test pass, even though i'm not handling the path `/api/users` in my `urls.py`?

Essentially, one could just write `factory.get('')` and it would pass. That doesn't make much sense, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in Django itself, the RequestFactory creates a dummy request object and directly calls the view (in this case the APIView).

If you want to test the complete stack (including urls.py and middlewares), use the test-client.

```
class TestTodoAppUsers(APITestCase):
    def test_get(self):
        response = self.client.get('/api/users')
        self.assertEqual(1, len(response.data))
```

I also used the APITestCase provided by DRF which provides `response.data` for you, see the the [testing docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing).